# How to assign foo.example.com to one IP address and example.com to a different one?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, ip-address

Say that I have a domain name called `example.com` and two server located at 2 different IP addresses: `1.2.3.4` and `6.7.8.9`.

How could I assign `example.com` to `1.2.3.4` and the subdomain `foo.example.com` to `6.7.8.9`?

[EDIT] I did try to put a A record linking from `@` to the first IP address and from `foo.example.com` to the second IP address, as illustrated below:

[image]

And I did configure a vhosts called `foo.example.com` on my server at IP address 2.

The `@` record works. But after 3 hours waiting for the result (DNS delay), nothing happened with `foo.example.com`, which link to nothing. Why?

Comment: If you need to debug your setup, use command line ping to see that you are hitting the correct IP address.  If the DNS isn't working yet, put the IP address in your `hosts.txt` file (or `/etc/hosts`) and test your server setup before the DNS goes through.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to edit the "domain name system" (DNS) records for your domain and assign two `A` records:  one for the bare domain, and one for the subdomain.   In DNS, `A` records are used to assign IP addresses to domain names (and subdomains).

The specific mechanics of editing your DNS records is going depend on where your DNS records are hosted.  My DNS host gives me a web interface that lets me do this:

[image: DNS A record web interface]

Comment: thank you for your help, however it does not works